# Print array column values into text area without null

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to print each column row values into a text area without null? If I do it within the while then I got perfect but I need print it in HTML code outside of the while. How do I get this.

```
$sdata = mysql_query("select (case when `EntryType` like '%Buildup%' then `EntryDescription` end) As cia,
    (case when `EntryType` like '%prelim%' or '%grinding%' then `EntryDescription` end) As grind,
    (case when `EntryType` like '%Covers%' then `EntryDescription` end) As covers,
    (case when `EntryType` like '%prelim%' or '%grinding%' then `EntryDescription` end) As buildup,
    (case when `EntryType` like '%Comment%' then `EntryDescription` end) As comments
  from `selectitem`
  JOIN `patient` on `patient`.`RecdNo` = `selectitem`.`RecordID`
  WHERE `patient`.`PatientID`='".$_GET['edit']."'");
```

Query Output:
[image]

```
while($data = mysql_fetch_array($sdata) ){

}
```

HTML Code Here:

```
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2"> <textarea rows="2" name="cia" style="width:90%;"><?php echo $data['cia']; ?></textarea> </label> </td>
        <td colspan="2"> <textarea rows="2" name="grind" style="width:100%;"><?php  ?> </textarea> </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2"><i>Covers</i> </td>
        <td colspan="2"><i>Build Up</i> </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td colspan="2"> <textarea rows="2" name="covers" style="width:90%;"><?php ?> </textarea> </label> </td>
        <td colspan="2"> <textarea rows="2" name="buildup" style="width:100%;"><?php ?> </textarea> </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td colspan="4"> <i>Comments</i>  </td> 
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="4"> <textarea rows="2" name="comments" style="width:100%;"><?php ?> </textarea></td>
    </tr>
```

Comment: simple, just take away the `while(){}` and make it `$data = mysql_fetch_array($sdata)`.  Oh yeah and [stop using mysql functions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php)

Comment: Sir, is that print all row for each column into a textarea?

Comment: it's print first row only.

Comment: My mistake I thought your query only returned one row.

Comment: Then how do I get it done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You still need to use the while loop, but assign the values to variables like this:

```
$cia ="";
$grind = "";

$count = mysql_num_rows($sdata); //count rows
$i=1; // set an iteration counter

while($data = mysql_fetch_array($sdata) ){

    if($i < $count){ // check if not last row and add newline if true
        $nl = "\r\n";
    } else {
        $nl = ""; // no newline if last row
    }

    if($data["cia"]){
        $cia .= $data["cia"] . $nl; // remember to change "\r\n" to $nl in all of these places
    }
    if($data["grind"]){
        $grind.= $data["grind"] . $nl;
    }

    $i++; //increase iteration counter
}
```

Then you output the variables in the textareas:

```
<tr>
    <td colspan="2"> <textarea rows="2" name="cia" style="width:90%;"><?php echo $cia; ?></textarea> </label> </td>
    <td colspan="2"> <textarea rows="2" name="grind" style="width:100%;"><?php echo $grind; ?> </textarea> </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td colspan="2"><i>Covers</i> </td>
    <td colspan="2"><i>Build Up</i> </td>
</tr>

<tr>
    <td colspan="2"> <textarea rows="2" name="covers" style="width:90%;"><?php ?> </textarea> </label> </td>
    <td colspan="2"> <textarea rows="2" name="buildup" style="width:100%;"><?php ?> </textarea> </td>
</tr>

<tr>
    <td colspan="4"> <i>Comments</i>  </td> 
</tr>
<tr>
    <td colspan="4"> <textarea rows="2" name="comments" style="width:100%;"><?php ?> </textarea></td>
</tr>
```

Comment: for other columns?

Comment: just assign the variables the same way as I did the other two.

Comment: each variable have a blank row at the end, how do I stop it?

Comment: You'll have to count the rows of the result and then only add a new line if it's not the last row. See my updated answer for how to do this.

Comment: I got it. Thank you Sir, for the best cooperation and kind behavior.